# Low views, high votes and unanswered

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, data-explorer

I was just mucking around with the data dump and came up with an interesting query:

Low views, high number of votes yet unanswered. http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/106

I thought the list was kind of cool.

I don't have too much of a question though, perhaps should this kind of sort order be integrated into the unanswered tab? (rational, give better exposure to good unanswered questions with a low view count)

Comment: How does a post have 1 view and 4 upvotes?

Comment: @Aarobot, a disturbance in the force perhaps :)

Comment: @aaro depends when it was asked. there were some bugs around viewcounts for a while

Answer (score 5):

I like it.  Might also be interesting to look for unanswered questions with high levels of traffic coming in from Google.

Comment: "high levels of traffic from google" == high views, not *low* views.

Comment: Yes, high views, but high views from people who have the same question, not people who know the answer.